# variant='label-hidden' Not Working for lightning-input-field When field is a Lookup

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I have a Lightning Web Component and in that I'm using a lighting-record-edit-form.  I'm trying to use a custom label for an input by hiding the default one for the lightning-input-field and adding my own.  I'm using the variant='label-hidden' and it isn't working.

It works on other fields, just not when the field rendered is a lookup field or a Rich Text field.

I've tried some different things with CSS but it doesn't seem to be picking it up.

I've seen some other similar questions with work arounds but they appear to only be for Aura components.

Anybody else encountered this or come up with a workaround?

```
<lighting-input-field field-name='Lookup_Field__c' variant='label-hidden'></lightning-input-field>
```

Comment: there are no css workarounds for lightning web components due to the nature of shadow dom

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Comment: Is there any solutions for it?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet.  I think we just have to wait for Salesforce to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I see its working now by using variant="label-hidden"

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input-field>
```

[image]

Comment: variant='label-hidden' is not working if Field Type is Rich text

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
         <label class="slds-form-element__label" >{labelSubject}</label>
         <lightning-input-field variant='label-hidden' field-name={nameField}  required></lightning-input-field>
</div>
```

Take a look at the [variants](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification) of this component to change the label's position

Comment: Was searching how to do for a while. Thanks @Emmanuel